# edit search.php to include subdomain posts

Tags: php, search

Is there a way for us to edit the search.php to include the subdomains with its search results?

The only "condition" the code has is...

...and I have really nothing more to go by. =/

And oh, I kinda want to avoid installing plug-ins, so please don't tell me to download and install the Multisite Global Search plugin.

Many thanks~